# Salesforce Release Process with ADO, previous release files and commits being displayed as new changes when a new PR to lower branches is created

Tags: azure-devops, salesforce, branch, release

How Is our Release branching strategy?

We have 3 branches: dev, uat and master.
We are using Azure Devops

1. Dev will create a Feature branch cloned from master.
2. Dev commit updated to Feature branches and Create first PR to Dev
3. Dev create second PR to UAT
4. Feature is approved in UAT sandbox
5. Release Manager creates a Release Branch from master
6. Feature branches are merged with release branches *using Cherry picks or PRs
7. Release branch is deployed in Prod
8. New pr is created from Release branch to Master

Now, the problem is when dev creates a new Feature Branch cloned from master and submit their first PR to dev or uat branch for a new release cycle all the files and commits from previous release are displayed as new changes in files and commits tabs of the PR. I understand it is related to a commit ID not present in dev or Uat but I don't know how to avoid it.

Number of files and commits not related to a particular feature makes developers and reviewers concern.

Comment: Hi, not very familiar with the Salesforce Release Process/Release Manager tool, could you kindly share screenshots to tell what do you want to achieve in Azure devops services point? If you want to find the commit id for branches in devops, you could directly go to Azure devops repos part->commits->choose the branch on the top->click into the specific commit and see the URL for the page:
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/webcopyfile/commit/{commit id}?refName=refs%2Fheads%2F1I.

Comment: Or you could run the rest api to get commit id:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

Comment: Hi @Fernanda, how's things going? Could you kindly tell whether you firstly do merge from dev branch/UAT branch to master branch, then clone a new feature branch then do commit to merge to dev branch/UAT branch? If so, the second merge direction seems incorrect. And could you clarify what do you want to avoid?